# Reintegrate a branch vs Merging Two Different Trees : TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I am planning to merge a branch to the trunk using TortoiseSVN explorer client. (I also need to do the opposite, i.e to merge from the trunk to a branch.)

#### My approach

This is how I plan to merge the branch to the trunk using Merging Two Different Trees:

`Merge Trunk in to Branch using tortoise`

Check out the trunk on my local box. Right click on checked out copy and then select Merging Two Different Trees. Under 
From: (start URL and revision of the range to merge), I will mention trunk URL and  under
To: (end URL and revision of the range to merge), I will mention branch URL

#### Alternatives

When I right click on trunk local copy and select Merge I see two related options

`1) Reintegrate a branch`

`2) Merging Two Different Trees`

But I am not sure what the difference is between them: which one is better to merge a branch to the trunk?

**Update :-** Most places I have read on the net say one should merge a branch back to the trunk using `Merge a range of revisions` (rather than `Reintegrate the branch`).
So to merge 100 revisions which are not sequential, I need to first note down those revisions and then mention those for `Merge a range of revisions`. Is that correct?

Comment: Can somebody explain the difference b/w Reintegrate a branch vs Merging Two Different Trees?

Comment: "Merging Two Different Trees" need for some special cases, do not use it if you not sure what are you doing.

Comment: If you use Tortoise and have committed with decent log messages, you will be able to recognise and select the revisions you want in the merge dialogue. _I shall add this to my answer._ That said, I hope you have fewer than 100 revisions: it is best not to leave it too long before merging: that way you can remember what you were doing better, and the branches will probably have diverged less, giving less risk of conflicts.

Comment: `Merge a range of revisions` is the way to go for merging across branch or to trunk or vice  versa. Just a not for my self :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to merge

You almost certainly want **Merge a range of revisions**, but you may see three possibilities in Tortoise:

- ***Reintegrate a branch***: **update your client!** *This no longer appears in Tortoise 1.8, which is better at working out how to merge.*
- *Merge a range of revisions*: Normally the trunk and a branch share a common origin, because one typically creates a branch from the trunk; they then start to diverge, and if you want to merge changes from one to the other (and your Subversion server is running at least 1.5), you should use *Merge a range of revisions*.
- *Merge two different trees*: If the branches in your repository were not created by a Subversion copy operation, or if you are using an old (pre 1.5) server) Subversion cannot so readily work out what it should change, and you need to give it more information. In this case you probably have to use *Merge two different trees*.

You may consider using the `svn` command without Tortoise, but I think you will find that Tortoise guides you through the process more smoothly, and that the `Edit conflicts` function – if you need it – is pretty helpful.

You may want to merge all changes or only some; in the latter case, if you use Tortoise and have committed with decent log messages, you will be able to recognise and select the revisions you want in the merge dialogue; already merged revisions will also be greyed out (for server > 1.5). That said, it is best not to leave it too long before merging: that way you can remember what you were doing better, and the branches will probably have diverged less, giving less risk of conflicts.

#### After the merge

If you see any conflicts as a result of the merge, it is handiest to keep the merge dialogue open and right-click one by one on the conflicted files, and choose *Edit conflicts* – this will show you places in your code which have been modified in both the trunk and the branch, and you will have to work out how to combine them by hand. If you do close the dialogue, you can use the *Check for modifications* dialogue to get the same possibilities; you can even use the *Commit* dialogue, but it is usually better not to actually commit until your merged code is correct.

Having resolved any conflicts, compile and test your system (preferably without making any unrelated modifications), and commit it once you are happy.
Do not worry too much that you will mess things up: because you always merge in a Working Copy, you will do no harm as long as you start with a clean slate do not commit prematurely.

#### References

*I suggest you also check out the Tortoise documentation of Merging at http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html and perhaps the Subversion documentation at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html for more details and tips.*

Comment: As per your latest answer it mean we should use `Merge a range of revisions` for  merging branch to trunk  with explicit mention of revision numbers as  'Reintegrate a branch:' is no more an option tortoise 1.8. Right ?

Comment: @emilly: I have checked out your update and extended and corrected my answer. I had not paid enough attention: I knew you did not want _Merge trees_, but I copied _Reintegrate_ from your post without noticing that it has disappeared in 1.8, and that what you want is really _Merge a range_ — sorry!

Comment: @emilly: You still do not have to specify a range: if you want to merge all available revisions, there is an options for that; otherwise, you are right.

Comment: say i created a branch and did commit under branch which revision numbers as 100, 105, 112, 120 
Now when i am merging brach to trunk(working copy) and i don't mention any revision number, then it will merge only 100,105,112,120
not inbetween sequence number like 101,102 etc which are revision number for some tree(branch/trunk). Is that correct?

Comment: It will only ever merge changes made to the branch from which you merge, ignoring revisions that did not affect it. So a range of revisions (or all revisions) means only those in that range that affected the source of the merge.